# Hidden focus on blur of an input element in dom

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, kendo-ui, kendo-listview

A little Explanation : I am using List view control of kendo UI(Telerik). I am triggering an update event of that control after editing the fields in list view. The list view control is having some text-boxes, a dropdown,checkbox and a submit button. When a user change something,  ideally it should trigger update but its not doing update because control is not able to judge if there  is a change  in model.

It is only working if I input something in textbox and just click on outside of textbox i.e just do a onblur before hitting submit. I don't know why it is happening but what I need is to just trigger a focus event but in a hidden mode so that user is unaware of it but it just happens after a user input something in textbox so that the list view control works successfully.

I am trying to do it like below but it will get noticed to user. How can i trigger focus in hidden mode after a user just enter something in textbox before hitting a submit?

```
 function BlurFunc() {
                    debugger;
                    $(this).closest('li').find('.inputField').focus();
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your code it is not clear whether you are using MVVM data binding to your model, but this may help; from http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/framework/mvvm/bindings/value:

> By default the value binding relies on the change DOM event, which is
>   raised after blurring the element whose value has changed. This means
>   that the value from the View-Model is updated when the element loses
>   focus. The data-value-update attribute can be used to specify a
>   different DOM event, such as keyup or keypress. The keydown event is
>   not supported, because the DOM element value is not yet updated when
>   that event triggers.

For example, try adding data-value-update="keyup" as an attribute to your text box input element:

```
<input data-value-update="keyup" data-bind="value: inputValue" />
```

This should then update the model value upon each key press and not wait until focus has been removed.